# Python: How can I find text between certain words in a string?

Tags: python, string, find, between

For example, there is a string or txt

```
"""
asfas @111 dfsfds @222 dsfsdfsfsd dsfds
dsfsdfs sdfsdgsd @333 dsfsdfs dfsfsdf @444 dfsfsd
dsfssgs sdsdg @555 fsfh
"""
```

Desired result:

```
"""
@111
@222
@333
@444
@555
"""
```

Using the code below, I can only see the first result.

```
import re
html="asfas @111 dfsfds @222 dsfsdfsfsd dsfds"
result = re.search('@"(.+?) ', html)
x = (result.group(0))
print(x)
```

**How do I improve my code?**

Comment: What about re.findall or re.finditer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `re.findall` method instead of `re.search` (re.search searches only for the first location where the regular expression pattern produces a match):

```
import re

txt = '''asfas @111 dfsfds @222 dsfsdfsfsd dsfds
dsfsdfs sdfsdgsd @333 dsfsdfs dfsfsdf @444 dfsfsd
dsfssgs sdsdg @555 fsfh'''

print(*re.findall(r'@\d+', txt), sep='\n')
```

Prints:

```
@111
@222
@333
@444
@555
```

Answer (score 2):

If you always have @ followed by 3 digits then:

```py
import re

text = '''asfas @111 dfsfds @222 dsfsdfsfsd dsfds
dsfsdfs sdfsdgsd @333 dsfsdfs dfsfsdf @444 dfsfsd
dsfssgs sdsdg @555 fsfh
'''

results = re.findall(r'(@\d{3})', text)

print(results)
```

So `()` means keep a pattern that has @ followed by only 3 digits.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this even without using regex :

```
html="asfas @111 dfsfds @222 dsfsdfsfsd dsfds"
x = [i for i in html.split() if i.startswith('@')]
```

**Output** :

```
['@111', '@222']
```